# VB.Net - Use wild card in My.Computer.Registry.GetValue

Tags: vb.net, registry, wildcard

I have a `VB.NET` script that looks up the current version of java installed. 
Everything worked great until java 8 came out.

Back in Java 7 i would do this.

```
My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment", "Java7FamilyVersion", Nothing)
```

In Java 8 (Java8FamilyVersion) is gone and has replaced with (FullVersion).
The problem is FullVersion is behind two more folders one with the version (18.0_25) Then another folder call MSI

So here is the problem; right now the first folder is called 18.0_25, but in the future it would be changed to something like 18.0.55ish.

I can't update my software that often, so i would like to use a wilcard in the getvalue
IE something like this

```
My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.8.*\MSI", "FullVersion", Nothing)
```

Above didn't work is their anything that would work?

Comment: Can you not grab a file version from a java dll or something?

Comment: I am looking into that right now any advice?

Comment: See below, but it may not suit your particular case. I use a similar function for an app of mine where I need to check for a specific dll version - it's posted as an answer simply because it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `GetSubKeyNames`method to enumerate the subkey(s) of "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment", then pick the alphabetically last (so that you do not fall for any old `1.7_`*xx* keys or the `1.8` key)

Answer (score 0):

You could grab a file version from one of the Java .dll files. Sorry, I don't have Java installed, but something like this might help you:

```
Dim fvi As FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("somefilename.dll")
Debug.Print(fvi.ProductVersion)
```

You can fiddle with the returned properties for major, minor, etc. You should be able to build a version string to get what you need.

Comment: I tried         Dim Java864 = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.ddl").ToString And it didn't work. Another issue is jre1.8.0_25 changing over time. Any advice?

Comment: @Itomship The path to the Java binaries is noted in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Java Runtime Environment\1.8\JavaHome and you can find the full path to jvm.dll in the same key under RuntimeLib