# Grab name of a folder in the directory VB.net

Tags: vb.net, directory, filepath

If you have the Java 8 installed and are running 64 and the lastest version you should have a folder called (jre1.0.0_25) 
It can be found here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`

How do you grab that name of the name file under Java, which will change over time (right now its jre1.0.0_25)?

I tried

```
New DirectoryInfo("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\").Name
```

But it didn't work.

Edit:

**Couple of questions have came up.**

1. This is part of a windows service i made the writes to a database
   Right now java isn't posting anything to the database so it errors out, due to it expecting and answer.
2. I have methods in place already for 32 bit vs 64 bit.
3. It is only used in house, i have complete control over how and where Java is installed.
4. It will also be in English.

Some guidance on this would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance

UPDATE: I am trying to convert the below solution to a function so i can output it to a database.

```
    Private Function java() As String
    Dim sourceDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), "Java")
    Dim dirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(sourceDir)
    For Each d In dirInfo.GetDirectories()
        Console.WriteLine(d.Name)
    Next

    java = Console.ReadLine()
    'Return dirInfo.ToString


End Function
```

Right now trying different things i can get the code to come up blank or with the path. 
Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We need to know exactly how it "didn't work." However...

You need to look at the results from DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories(), something like this:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim sourceDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), "Java")
        Dim dirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(sourceDir)
        For Each d In dirInfo.GetDirectories()
            Console.WriteLine(d.Name)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

which, on my computer, outputs:

```
jre1.8.0_25
jre6
jre7
```

You will have to decide how to figure out which is the directory you want.

I used `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)` as the "Program Files(x86)" directory might be named something else if Windows is a different language version. However, the Java installer does allow it to be installed somewhere else, so if you wanted to make it more robust you would have to investigate how to locate the installation.

**BUT** if the intent is to find out the currently installed version of Java, you should probably check the registry: more information at [Deploying the JRE on Windows](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/runtime-windows-137915.html) - and I'm sure you can do some searching to find out if that still applies for Java 8.

**INSPECTING JAVA.DLL**

Some notes:

- It appears to be possible to have Java 7 and Java 8 installed side-by-side for the x86 version
- You can also have x86 Java 7 and x64 Java 8 installed
- If your program is compiled to run as x86, `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` points to the same location as `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86`, so it will not detect the x64 version of Java
- x64 Java 8 reports its version as `8.0` (phew! I thought it was going to be 1.8 from the directory name and the way `java -version` reports "java version "1.8.0_25").
- For robustness, you're going to have to consider what you might have installed and adjust the code accordingly.

I came up with this:

```
Function GetMaxJavaVersion() As Decimal
    ' N.B. If this program is run as x86 then the 64-bit Program Files directory will not be accessed even
    ' with Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles
    Dim sourceDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), "Java")
    ' search in all the subdirectories for "java.dll"
    Dim javaDlls = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "java.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

    ' arrange it so that 0 is returned if not found
    Dim versions As New List(Of Decimal) From {0D}

    For Each jd In javaDlls
        Console.WriteLine(jd)
        Dim versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(jd)
        versions.Add(CDec(String.Format("{0}.{1}", versionInfo.ProductMajorPart, versionInfo.ProductMinorPart)))
    Next

    Return versions.Max

End Function
```

I'm sure you can modify it to check both x86 and "normal" Program Files directories.

Comment: My intent is to grab the currently installed version of Java. I used to use the registry for this, but the Java 8 has an issue. See my other post about the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593347/vb-net-use-wild-card-in-my-computer-registry-getvalue

Comment: I answered you questions in my original post. I will start looking into your answer.

Comment: It would have been useful if you had given a link to your other post in this question ;) I suppose you could look in each of the directories for `java.dll` and, if it exists, get its version, then, if there is more than one, choose the highest one.

Comment: I thought about that, but i didn't know if i should.

Comment: I like you solution but am having trouble converting it to a function (see above)

Comment: Unfortunately java.dll has the same issue with changing path with each version.

Comment: @Itomship I've edited my answer to include a way of finding and getting the product versions of java.dll files.